# The truth value of a Series is ambiguous using if condtition

Tags: python

Getting the following error:

> The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."

for the below code.

```
if (right_coordinate == shape['x']) | (left_coordinate == shape['x'] + shape['cx']):
```

Comment: A google search for your error sent me here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36921951/truth-value-of-a-series-is-ambiguous-use-a-empty-a-bool-a-item-a-any-o

Comment: Try if (right_coordinate == shape['x']) or (left_coordinate == shape['x'] + shape['cx'])

Comment: So which sense did you want? The options listed in the error message can give different answers.

Comment: | is the bitwise operator. You probably want the logical operator `or`

Comment: `shape['x']` is a list of values. Do you want the comparison to be true if _any_ are true or if _all_ are true? That's the ambiguity.